# Как в JavaScript настроить событие по нажатию Enter?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть игра, которая сейчас запускается по клику на кнопку:

start.addEventListener('click', startGame)

Но мне надо сделать так, чтобы она запускалась нажатием Enter. Как это сделать?

Comment: `keydown`/`keyup`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#event_listing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно повесить событие клавиатуры на элемент, который в фокусе, или на документ, и проверить, что клавиша enter.

```js
document.addEventListener( 'keyup', event => {
  if( event.code === 'Enter' ) console.log('enter was pressed');
});
```